# Keycloak Execution Flow

Tags: keycloak

I'm a little confused with configuring alternative execution flows.

I currently have the follow configured.

```
Cookie                         <- Alternative
Username Password Form         <- Required
TOTP Configured?               <- Alternative
                OTP Form       <- Optional
No, SMS then                   <- Alternative
                SMS Auth       <- Optional
```

As you can guess, I want SMS auth to trigger if OTP is not configured for the user.

At the moment it seems that if OTP isn't configured, the OTP Form is skipped and authentication is successful and SMS is skipped.  Is there a way to tell keycloak the if OTP is not configured then the 'TOTP Configured?' execution flow has failed, so the 'No, SMS then' execution flow is actioned?

(In the source code it looks like context.success() is called if OTP is not configured for the user.)

I'm using Keycloak 7.0.0

Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 2):

Usually top level executions or sub-flow must be **Alternative** for browser flow (Cookie is enough for authentication in application if you are already passed **Password && (OTP || SMS)**). From my point of view flow should be like this:

```
Cookie                      ->    Alternative
Forms (Sub-flow)            ->    Alternative
    Password                ->    Required
    2FA (Sub-flow)          ->    Required
        OTP                 ->    Alternative
        SMS                 ->    Alternative
```

So if we reach credentials verification stage: we MUST pass Password verification then we MUST pass one of 2FA authenticators (OTP or SMS). But SMS and OTP authenticators should be properly implemented (Possibly you will have to tune their source code. See keycloak src and [Keycloak customization docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/7.0/server_development/index.html)).